# What is an alternate way to implement PdfContentByte and PdfTemplate in iText 7

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I am working on migration from iText 5 to iText 7. I have iText 5 code as below. I am not sure which alternative from iText 7(may be Canvas) should be used to implement `PdfContentByte` and `PdfTemplate`.

```
produce(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer, width, height, ...) {
     com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
     com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfTemplate template = cb.createTemplate(width, height);
     try
    {
        template.beginText();

        template.setFontAndSize(font, fontSize);

        template.setTextMatrix(0, 0);

        template.showTextAligned(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, value, width/2, linePos, 0);
        template.endText();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {   
    }

    cb.addTemplate(template, left, areaTop - top - height);
}
```

Can anyone please suggest the correct alternative to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `PdfContentByte` instance returned by iText 5 `PdfWriter.getDirectContent()` essentially is the content of the current page plus a number of methods to add more content.

An iText 5 `PdfTemplate` essentially is a PDF form XObject and its content plus a number of methods to add more content.

In iText 7 there are dedicated classes `PdfPage` and `PdfFormXObject` for pages and PDF form XObjects respectively, and there are classes `PdfCanvas` and `Canvas` providing low level and high level methods respectively to add more content to pages or form XObjects.

Thus, the following corresponds approximately to your iText 5 code:

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = ...
PdfPage page = ... // e.g. pdfDoc.addNewPage();

PdfFormXObject pdfFormXObject = new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle(width, height));
try (Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfFormXObject, pdfDoc)) {
    canvas.showTextAligned(value, width/2, linePos, TextAlignment.CENTER);
}

PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
pdfCanvas.addXObject(pdfFormXObject, left, bottom);
```

*(From [AddCanvasToDocument](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/content/AddCanvasToDocument.java#L111) test `testAddCanvasForManjushaDC`)*

I say "approximately" because the architecture of iText 5 and iText 7 differ, so there is not necessarily an exact correspondence, in particular best practices in iText 5 don't directly translate to best practices in iText 7.