# iText7 - Unable to find alternative code in iText 7 version

Tags: java, itext, itext7

```
PdfContentByte[] canvases;    
PdfContentByte pdfcb = canvases[PdfPTable.LINECANVAS];
```

I am unable to find the alternative of above lines of code (iText 5) for iText 7 version.

Comment: Did you have a look at this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63055889/what-is-an-alternate-way-to-implement-pdfcontentbyte-and-pdftemplate-in-itext-7

Comment: The two lines of code you show cannot work, even for iText 5 - you have a `null` array and try to access one of its members...